# An example of an ultrafilter

Tags: boolean-algebra, filters

This is Theorem 3.5 (pp. 150) of the book "A course in universal algebra."
http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/UALG/univ-algebra.pdf

Theorem 3.15. Let $\bf B$ be a Boolean algebra.

(a) (Stone) If $a \in B -\{0\}$, then there is a prime ideal $I$ such that $a \notin I$.

(b) If $a \in B-\{1\}$, then there is an ultrafilter $U$ of $\bf B$ with $a\notin U$.

I am having a hard time finding a non-trivial example  of $a$, $U$, and $\bf B$ (resp. $a$, $I$, and $\bf B$) that satisfies (b) (resp. (a)).

I will appreciate if someone gives me an example of $a$, $U$, and $\bf B$ (resp. $a$, $I$, and $\bf B$) that satisfies (b) (resp. (a)).

Answer (score 4):

Let $X$ be any infinite set, let $\mathbf B$ be the Boolean algebra consisting of the finite subsets of $X$ and their complements, let $a$ be any finite subset of $X$, and let $U$ consist of all the complements of finite subsets of $X$.

You can get more examples by changing "infinite" and "finite" to "uncountable" and "countable", or to "of cardinality $\geq\kappa$" and "of cardinality $<\kappa$" for your favorite infinite cardinal number $\kappa$.

Comment: Is that an ultrafilter ? Let $X = \mathbb{N}$, $B = P(\mathbb{N})$ and $U$ as you defined it for $a = \{1,2\}$. If we let $E\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ be the even numbers, $E \notin U$ nor $E^c$. Hence it is not an ultrafilter. The sole construction I know is over $\mathbb{N}$, it is a bit tricky and involves Zorn's Lemma.

Comment: @DiegoAsterio The $U$ in my answer is an ultrafilter in the $\mathbf B$ in my answer. Your comment is about a different $B$, namely $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$.

Comment: You wrote any infinite set and I provided you with a different set $\mathbb{N}$ where all your premises hold and that is not an ultrafilter, what tells there is a counter example to what you said. I agree your example is a filter although not an ultra filter. In other words does it hold that for every $a$ either $a$ is in $U$ or $\not A$ is in $U$. It is true that any filter can be extended to an ultrafilter although that is not what you have said

Comment: @DiegoAsterio My answer is correct for all infinite sets $X$, including $X=\mathbb N$, if you use the $\mathbf B$ in my answer. If you change $B$, that's another story, irrelevant to my answer.

Comment: The Boolean algebra consisting of the finite subsets of X, their complements, and union and intersection as operations ?

Comment: @DiegoAsterio Yes, but of course complementation is also one of the Boolean operations.

Comment: Then why do you say I have changed $B$, I am sticking to what you have written and found an example where everything holds and is not an ultrafilter.

Comment: @DiegoAsterio Your $B$ has a lot more elements than mine. Yours contains all subsets of $\mathbb N$; mine contains only the finite sets and their complements. In particular, the set $E$ in your first comment is not in my $\mathbf B$.

Comment: It is true, I am so ashamed and sorry. Thank you for your last reply it was very clarifying.